# How to add a value to a column based on specific column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name      Owner    Date         Total
Asun      Louise   14/02/2020    75
Rodrigo   Matt     11/02/2020    67
Asun      Louise   10/20/2020    nan
```

I would like the dataframe to have the same value in the Total column.

```
Name      Owner    Date         Total
Asun      Louise   14/02/2020    75
Rodrigo   Matt     11/02/2020    67
Asun      Louise   10/20/2020    75
```

I got really stuck with this. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: The formatting was all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non missing value per groups and repalce missing values of `Total` column by it with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].fillna(df.groupby(['Name','Owner'])['Total'].transform('first'))
print (df)
      Name   Owner        Date  Total
0     Asun  Louise  14/02/2020   75.0
1  Rodrigo    Matt  11/02/2020   67.0
2     Asun  Louise  10/20/2020   75.0
```